# Get filename after filereader asynchronously loaded a file

Tags: javascript, android, cordova, fileapi

I am loading several files in a directory in order to parse some data from them. This works great so far, but I would like to know which file I am looking at. So I need the name of the file after it was loaded.
Can anybody help on that?

// gets all files in dir

```
function updateData(){
  var dirReader = approot.createReader();

  var fail =failCB('Error - Directory for parsing failed to open'); // logs fail...
  dirReader.readEntries(parseData,fail); 
}
```

// loading each file

```
function parseData(entries){
  var i;
  for (i=0; i<entries.length; i++) {
    var reader = new FileReader();
    reader.onloadend = createListItem;
    reader.readAsText(entries[i]);
  }
}
```

// HERE I WOULD LIKE TO KNOW THE NAME !!!!

```
function createListItem(evt){
    // it gives me all the loaded data. But based on which file it was, I would like to handle it!
  console.log(evt.target.result)
    // lets say something like this
    $('#content').find(   file.name   ).append(evt.target.result);
  }
}
```

Answer (score 47, accepted):

Create a closure around the `File` to capture the current file. Then you can get the filename.

An example: http://www.html5rocks.com/en/tutorials/file/dndfiles/#toc-reading-files

Closure to capture the file information.

```
function parseData(entries){
  for (var i=0; i<entries.length; i++) {
    reader.onloadend = (function(file) {
      return function(evt) {
        createListItem(evt, file)
      };
    })(entries[i]);
    reader.readAsText(entries[i]);
  }
}
```

And the called function gets an additional argument

```
function createListItem(evt, file) {
  console.log(evt.target.result)
  console.log(file.name);
}
```

Comment: it looks good! but could you please post your answer/example here... and i would like to know how that closure works.

Comment: there are some parts iam not getting:
1. for (var i = 0, f; f = files[i]; i++)
what is that doin i have never seen this way writing a for loop
2. your onload = ('long function call' )( f ) , also never seen ^^what does it do and how / why there is an f behind the function?

Comment: The better way to do it, would be to attach your file entry as a property to your reader, as demonstrated in this users question:
http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4404361/html5-file-api-get-file-object-within-filereader-callback/4404427#4404427

Comment: Many thanks. In Angular, I had to bind `this`  - `reader.onload = (function(filename){
       return function(event){
         this.handleReaderLoaded(event,filename);
       }
      }(uploadedFilename)).bind(this);` and `handleReaderLoaded(event: FileReaderProgressEvent, filename) {
    console.log('loaded file ',filename);...}`

Answer (score 20):

The following source code add an attribute to the file reader

```
    for(i=0; i < files.length; i++)
    {
        var fileReader = new FileReader();
        fileReader.onload = function(file)
        {
              // DO what you need here
              // file name = file.target.fileName
        } // end of reader load
        fileReader.fileName = files[i].name;
        fileReader.readAsBinaryString(files[i]);
    }
```

Comment: when I do this in my Angular code, the IDE complains that fileName doesn't exist in fileReader. I know that we are adding the property but Angular doesn't let this compile.

Comment: add an attribute to the file reader , this works well.