# How to narrow down my base64 image url to just the image name?

Tags: php, mysql, phpmyadmin

**php script:**

```
$contentType = isset($_SERVER["CONTENT_TYPE"]) ? trim($_SERVER["CONTENT_TYPE"]) : '';

if ($contentType === "application/json") {
  //Receive the RAW post data.
  $content = trim(file_get_contents("php://input"));

  $decoded = json_decode($content, true);

  //If json_decode failed, the JSON is invalid.
  if(! is_array($decoded)) {
      echo "Invalid json";

  } else {
      $image=$decoded['image'];
  }
}
```

[image]

As you can see in the above given picture, I just want to upload the image file name and not its base64 encoded string. How do I do that?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

**Unfortunalety you can't**

> The base64 string doesn't contain the file name, only the contents of the file ([source](https://stackoverflow.com/a/47526437/14648997))

However, if you have control over the client which is sending the encoded image, you can add the filename in the json payload like this :

```
{
  "image": "your base64 encoded image",
  "filename": "image file name"
}
```

And get it on your php code :

```
$contentType = isset($_SERVER["CONTENT_TYPE"]) ? trim($_SERVER["CONTENT_TYPE"]) : '';

if ($contentType === "application/json") {
  //Receive the RAW post data.
  $content = trim(file_get_contents("php://input"));

  $decoded = json_decode($content, true);

  //If json_decode failed, the JSON is invalid.
  if(! is_array($decoded)) {
      echo "Invalid json";

  } else {
      $image=$decoded['image'];
      $fileName=$decoded['filename'];
  }
}
```