# How to get path directory from FileReader()?

Tags: javascript, jquery

Hi i have these codes to read the file the user has uploaded:

```js
function readURL(input) {
  if (input.files && input.files[0]) {
    var reader = new FileReader();

    reader.onload = function(e) {
      $('#myImg').attr('src', e.target.result);
    }

    reader.readAsDataURL(input.files[0]);
  }
}
```

And the output is a whole chunk of data:

[image]

Is there any way i can get the path from the data? for example `C:\Users\blackLeather\Desktop`

If no,is there another way to get the image directory without having to add into another folder?

Comment: Nope! This is not possible!

Comment: @16kb okay.Thank you for ur response.

Comment: That is not possible!

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How to get the filename from the Javascript FileReader?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/24245105/how-to-get-the-filename-from-the-javascript-filereader)

Answer (score 9, accepted):

> Is there any way i can get the path from the data?

No. None at all. That information is not provided to the JavaScript layer by the browser, for security reasons.

Answer (score 1):

Add this in element:

```
onchange="loadFile(event)
```

```
var loadFile = function(event) {
    var image = document.getElementById('output');
    image.src = URL.createObjectURL(event.target.files[0]);
};
```

Comment: This does not answer the question. What was asked for is impossible as T.J. Crowder correctly stated.

Answer (score 0):

Like stated before you can't get the URL where the file lived, but you can create one.

```
function createFileURL() {
     var uploadedFile = document.getElementById("customFile").files[0];
     var reader = new FileReader();
     reader.readAsDataURL(uploadedFile);
     reader.onload = function () {
        return URL.createObjectURL(uploadedFile);
     }
  }
```