# Trying to get filereader.readAsDataURL into an object array so that I can display the image from the drag and drop event

Tags: javascript

I have a Drag and Drop event that is connected to my imageDrop function. I am trying to get the dataurl into an array so that I can display images via a slider view or a grid view. I am able to get the name of the file and the type I just need help figuring out how to get it to display the image.

I have tried setting up the reader.onload but when i run the page it does not output the expected values

```
  imageDrop(e) {
        e.stopPropagation();
        e.preventDefault();
        let dt = e.dataTransfer;
        for(var i = 0, n= dt.files.length; i < n; i++){
            var file = dt.files[i];
            var reader = new FileReader();
            reader.onload = (function(f){
                return function(e){
                    e.target.result;
                }
            });(file)
            this.imageFiles.push({
                name: dt.files[i].name,
                data: reader.readAsDataURL(file),
                type: dt.files[i].type
            });
        }
   }
```

What I am expecting is to get the name of the file, the type and the dataurl to display the image into the imageFiles array.

Comment: I'm afraid that isn't possible [How to get path directory from FileReader()?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/53759070/how-to-get-path-directory-from-filereader)

Comment: Not trying to get the path , trying to put the base64 encode into an array so i can then use the repeat function of lit-element to render the image out to the browser. I never said anything about getting the file path .

Comment: Note that you absolutely don't need the FileReader here, nor any asynchronous scripting: `imageDrop(e) { e.stopPropagation(); e.preventDefault();
this.imageFiles.push.apply(this.imageFiles, ( [...e.dataTransfer.files].map( (f) => ({ name: f.name, data: URL.createObjectURL(f), type: f.type }) )
 ) );
}` is all you need: https://jsfiddle.net/8va0r4tw/

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The problem lies in your `onload` callback function and the `array` `push` that follows. The push to the array occurs first and so the values are added to the array without the `data` property, because at that time, there is no value. That value can be retrieved from within the `onload` callback.

You'll want to have the image added to the array whenever the image has been decoded into a `base64` string.

You can do that by moving the `this.imageFiles.push` into the `load` event callback. When the `load` event is called the `reader.result` value has been updated and now contains the `base64` string you require.

I assume that this is a method of a class you are writing because you are referring to `this`. So I've used an `arrow function` to make `this` refer to the context of the class.

```
imageDrop(e) {
    e.stopPropagation();
    e.preventDefault();
    let dt = e.dataTransfer;
    for(var i = 0, n = dt.files.length; i < n; i++){
        const file = dt.files[i];
        const reader = new FileReader();
        reader.addEventListener('load', () => {
            this.imageFiles.push({
                name: file.name,
                data: reader.result,
                type: file.type
            });
        }, {once: true});
        reader.readAsDataURL(file)
    }
}
```

Try it out and I hope it fixes your problem.

Comment: With some minor changes it does work as expected I had to change the dt.files.name to file.name and same with type and it all worked out. Thank you for your help

Comment: You are welcome. I've added your minor change to the answer.

Comment: I did some more testing, I am able to process one image at a time, but when I do multiple images it only collects data from the last file that was dropped and processes it the number of times as files that I dropped in .  sometimes I get 2 sometimes I get one but it is all the same data 


0: {name: "ashes-of-creation-title copy.jpg", data: "", type: "image/jpeg"}

1: {name: "ashes-of-creation-title copy.jpg", data: "data:image/jpeg;base64,/9j/4RTIRXhpZgAATU0AKgAAAAg...,

2: {name: "ashes-of-creation-title copy.jpg", data: "data:image/jpeg;base64,/9j/4RTIRXhpZgAATU0AKgAAAA...

Comment: I've added a closure to the `load` event handler. Try it out and let me know if it works.

Comment: Using `const file = dt.files[i];` instead of `var` might also solve the problem.

Comment: had to make some minor changes again,  had to add t as a parameter then this with the file, reader and then the array to t.imageFiles and it all works correctly I get all the images that are dropped and the data .. thanks again for your help ..

Comment: Great to hear. I realized that the closure changed the context of `this` and tried another approach which uses `const` and should have the same result. Answer is based on [this](https://decembersoft.com/posts/understanding-javascript-closures-in-for-loops/) article.