# Get name from submitted Folder

Tags: angular, filereader

When Using this Input:

```
<input type="file" id="file" (change)="useFiles($event)" webkitdirectory directory multiple/>
```

I get an Object array with all the files inside the folder.

With a fileReader i can read the content and the names of the files:

```
  public readFolder(files: any[]) {
    this.fileCache = [];
    this.readFile(0, files);
    return this.folderReader$.asObservable();
  }

  private readFile(index, files) {
    const reader = new FileReader();
    if (index >= files.length) {
      this.folderReader$.next(this.fileCache);
      return;
    }
    const file = files[index];
    const filename = file.name;
    reader.onload = (e: any) => {
      this.fileCache.push({
        name: filename,
        content: e.target.result});
      this.readFile(index + 1, files);
    };
    reader.readAsText(file);
  }
}
```

Now, Is there any possibility to get the name of the Folder using this FileReader? what would be an easy way to get the name of the folder from input?

I am NOT searching on how to get the Path of the files but how to get the name of the folder i am submitting for input.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How to get path directory from FileReader()?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/53759070/how-to-get-path-directory-from-filereader)

Comment: Not path direcotry but the name of the folder i am giving for input

Comment: @Liam when clicking on the input i choose a folder, isn't it possible to get it's name?

Comment: It seems strange to me that I can't get the Name of the Object i'm choosing for input. This has nothing to do with the path has it?

Comment: It seems this is locked down for security reasons. Typically browsers can't interact with the file system of the client. Otherwise virus JS would be a thing. Couple of people here seem to have [potentially working solutions](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/24245105/how-to-get-the-filename-from-the-javascript-filereader)

Comment: I now found out theres a solution for my question: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/24718769/html5-javascript-how-to-get-the-selected-folder-name is this also not secure?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [html5/Javascript - How to get the Selected folder name?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/24718769/html5-javascript-how-to-get-the-selected-folder-name)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you get the whole filePath you can use [Node.js path API](https://nodejs.org/api/path.html) with [basename](https://nodejs.org/api/path.html#path_path_basename_path_ext) function:

```
var path = require('path');
path.basename(path.dirname(filename));
```