# Syncfusion UploadChangeEventArgs

Tags: syncfusion, ej2-syncfusion, syncfusion-blazor

I tried to get the FilePath dynamically on user's selection. Syncfusion documentation says that var path = file.FileInfo.FileSource gets the filepath selected by browser, however it returns null.

What is the way to get the file path dynamically not hardcoded. I am able to get the filepath with hardcoded but I don't want this way.

```
private async Task OnChange(UploadChangeEventArgs args)
    {
        var fileProcess = new LoadExcelData(Logger, Configuration);

        // var filePath = @"C:\Users\xxx\Desktop\DataServices\";
        foreach (var file in args.Files)
        {
            var path = file.FileInfo.FileSource;
            await fileProcess.ProcessExcelFiles(path, UpdateProgressBar); 
        }
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

You cannot retrieve the selected file path on both the client side and server side due to security reasons. Please refer to the following common links for more information:

- https://forums.asp.net/t/1917545.aspx?how+to+get+the+full+path+of+the+file+name+that+is+selected+using+fileupload+control
- [How to get path directory from FileReader()?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/53759070/how-to-get-path-directory-from-filereader)