# Pass argument into the onloadend function of FileReader

Tags: javascript, asynchronous, filereader

I'm using `readAsDataURL` to convert blobs into base64. The problem is that I'm doing that in a loop:

```
var reader = new FileReader();

for(var index in objects){
   reader.readAsDataURL(objects[index].blob);
}

reader.onloadend = function() {
   // need to pass my index here
   objects[index].base64 = reader.result;
}
```

So my first question is can I use the same reader for all my blobs? And if yes how can I pass the **index** into my `onloadend` function?

If I can't use the same reader, how should I do to solve this?

Answer (score 0):

Now, I will admit my answer was written pretty quickly as my laptop is dying, but I believe the code below should solve your problem.

```
function readAllBlobs(objects, callback) {
    var index = 0;
    var reader = new FileReader();

    function readBlob(object) {
        reader.readAsDataURL(object.blob);
    }

    var readBlobHandler = function () {
        // the index is available here.
        objects[index].base64 = reader.result;

        index++;
        if (index == objects.length) {
            // all objects have been read, fire callback on mutated objects array.
            callback(objects);
            return;
        }

        readBlob(objects[index]);
    }

    reader.onload = readBlobHandler;

    readBlob(objects[index]);
}
```

I was thinking you could write a function that accepts your array of blob objects and a callback. The function uses a single FileReader with an onload handler that continually increments an index and reads the next object in the array that was passed in. The index is always available, as this logic is executed within a closure as opposed to a for loop. Once the index has been incremented to the same length as the objects array that was passed in, your callback is executed with the mutated objects array passed as a parameter. This callback should hold the logic you want to execute once all blobs have been converted to base64.

Hope this helps!

Comment: I have found this very nice solution: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4404361/html5-file-api-get-file-object-within-filereader-callback?rq=1